# Convert date with timezone

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar, timezone

I am getting date from server: **2022-12-14 20:59:59 +0000**
I have view with promo codes, so according to received date I should show after how many seconds it will be expired.

For example if my current date is **2022-12-14 19:59:59 +0000**, I must show 60:00 seconds.
If the users timezone is GMT+4, he must see 60:00 seconds as well.

So I use this code:

```
 let currentTime = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
 let expirationDate = model.expirationDate

 expiredText = expirationDate.dateStringWithFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
 timeLeft = Int(expirationDate.timeIntervalSince1970) - currentTime
```

**Result is:**
currentTime: 2022-12-14 13:48:16 +0000    // my current time is 16:48:16

expirationDate: 2022-12-14 20:59:59 +0000

timeLeft: "0d. 07:11:43"

So Date() returns wrong date.

I tried to use calendar, but result is the same.

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let currentDate = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:Z"
dateFormatter.timeZone = calendar.timeZone
```

How can I correctly convert my timezone to timezone of received date or vice versa?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making this more complicated than it is.

We have a server timestamp

```
let serverDate = "2022-12-14 20:59:59 +0000"
```

that we convert to a `Date` using a formatter

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
```

Then we want to calculate the difference between the server data and now

```
if let expirationDate = dateFormatter.date(from: serverDate) {
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: .now, to: expirationDate)
}
```

and then we can use a `DateComponentsFormatter` to get the difference as a string

```
let compFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
print(compFormatter.string(from: components))
```

Comment: Printed result is "5:55:46", but my current time is 19:05, my timezone is GMT+4. So it had to be "1:55:00".

Comment: But server time is GMT so the difference is 5:55 if you add four hours to the server time as well.

Comment: serverDate has +0000 timezone, but every user has its own timezone, I need to show the same value for everyone, for example after 01:22:00 the promo code will be expired. When I compare Calendar's .now with serverDate I'm not get the same result for everyone.

Comment: If the time is 00:00 in GMT+4 then doesn't the code expire in 59 minutes (20:59 GMT+0)?

Comment: @Dev11_1 If your local time is 19:05+0400 then that means your time is 15:05+0000. If it expires at 21:00+0000 then it is correct that it expires in 5:55, not 1:55.